# Send DM Through A Member's Username

Tags: javascript, discord.js

> I accidentally did this once, I know it is possible, However I can't replicate what I did before.

I want to know how to send a DM to a user through their username.
For example the query **!msg ThisUser "This Is A Message"** would DM Them "This Is A Message"

The Goal is not mentioning the user, But to send the message manually to them

My Attempt

```
const memberList = message.guild.members.cache.filter(user => !user.user.bot).array().map(user => user.user.username)

memberList[14].send('Hello')
```

Comment: Do you have any errors or is it partially working or are there no errors but just doesn't work?

Comment: I simply get `TypeError: memberList[14].send is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```
if(message.content.startsWith('!msg'){
   const args = message.content.slice(4).split(/ +/);
   const username = args[0];
   const content = args[1];
   let member = message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.username === username);
   member.user.send(content);
}
```

Comment: You should add a **catch** function to **member.user.send()** since this function may return an error due to the user's privacy settings.

Comment: Yeah, you will need to handle all the possible errors, for example, receiving that command in DMs will make your bot throw an error, because of message.guild . This is just some basic code to give you an idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, Here it is for anyone else

```
// Get the user objects of every member
const memberList = message.guild.members.cache.filter(user => !user.user.bot).array().map(user => user.user)

// Have a variable represent whether the user was found or not
const targetFound = memberList.find(member => member.username == args[1])

// Declare the message to send (args is predefined)
const messageToSend = args.splice(2).join(' ')

// If the username was found, send the message to them
if (targetFound) targetFound.send(messageToSend)
```